# Getting Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-player

I am using react player in my react typescript project. I am using a material UI volume slider to set the volume of react video player.

the volume value will be between 0 - 1 so for calculating the value with respect to the slider i created a function.

```
const handleState = (newValue: any) => {
    setState({ ...state, volume:parseFloat(newValue/100)});
  };
```

the initial value of my volume is 0.5. I set it using useState

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    volume: 0.5
  });
```

My call on the volume slider

```
<Slider
            min={0}
            max={100}
            value={50}
            onChange={handleState}
          />
```

I am getting error on `newValue/100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **[parseFloat(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) receive a string**

**So add a `Number(newValue)` and `toString()` at the end would fix it:**

```
const handleState = (newValue: any) => {
    setState({ ...state, volume:parseFloat((Number(newValue)/100).toString())});
  };
```

Comment: Yeah, `parseFloat(string)` receive a string. I updated the answer

Comment: Hey @RabnerCasandara, Just update the final solution, see if it works for you